# Performance testing an Azure Netapp instance

Tags: performance, netapp, azure-networking

We are looking to run a Netapp instance in Azure Ireland.  The first time our cloud architect tried it performance was terrible. We therefore want to run some performance tests but are hitting a brick wall.

I can traceroute to the Netapp instance but don't have access to a shell to even traceroute back to see what path the data is taking.  I don't have any tools like iperf or even smokeping to see what the issues are in the data path (MTU?  fragmentation?  Too long a reverse path?  Overloaded link in reverse path?  etc)  How do users debug performance issues when using Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate about what performance indicators you find to be troublesome? Can you give us some more details from where you are connecting?

Comment: We have a 10Gb/sec connection and are only able to upload about 7GB in an hour or so.  I'd like to do some performance debugging and find a lack of tools available to debug the underlying infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

File sharing protocols like smb, cifs, and nfs are not optimized for high latency. They will probably have horrible throughput over your wan. These protocols are designed to be used from within the same network- test again from a server in the same azure datacenter and ideally network.

Comment: Strange then that Netapp and MS market it as a solution:  https://www.netapp.com/us/cloud-marketplace/microsoft-azure.aspx     https://cloud.netapp.com/storage-solutions-for-azure

Comment: Not at all strange. Everything they say is assuming you were accessing this from a local network.